# Java reflection to set static final field fails after previous reflection

Tags: reflection, java-8, java

In Java, it turns out that field accessors get cached, and using accessors has side-effects. For example:

```
class A {
    private static final int FOO = 5;
}

Field f = A.class.getDeclaredField("FOO");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.getInt(null); // succeeds

Field mf = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers" );
mf.setAccessible(true);

f = A.class.getDeclaredField("FOO");
f.setAccessible(true);
mf.setInt(f, f.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
f.setInt(null, 6); // fails
```

whereas

```
class A {
    private static final int FOO = 5;
}

Field mf = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers" );
mf.setAccessible(true);

f = A.class.getDeclaredField("FOO");
f.setAccessible(true);
mf.setInt(f, f.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
f.setInt(null, 6); // succeeds
```

Here's the relevant bit of the stack trace for the failure:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set static final int field A.FOO to (int)6
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwFinalFieldIllegalAccessException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwFinalFieldIllegalAccessException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedStaticIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.setInt(UnsafeQualifiedStaticIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:129)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.setInt(Field.java:949)
```

These two reflective accesses are of course happening in very different parts of my code base, and I don't really want to change the first to fix the second. Is there any way to change the second reflective access to ensure it succeeds in both cases?

I tried looking at the `Field` object, and it doesn't have any methods that seem like they would help. In the debugger, I noticed `overrideFieldAccessor` is set on the second `Field` returned in the first example and doesn't see the changes to the modifiers. I'm not sure what to do about it, though.

If it makes a difference, I'm using `openjdk-8`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the modifier hack (don't forget [it is a total hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)) to work, you need to change the `modifiers` private field *before* the first time you access the field.

So, before you do `f.getInt(null);`, you need to do:

```
mf.setInt(f, f.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
```

The reason is that only one internal `FieldAccessor` object is created for each field of a class (*), no matter how many different actual  `java.lang.reflect.Field` objects you have. And the check for the `final` modifier is done once when it constructs the FieldAccessor implementation in the [`UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/reflect/UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java#UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor%28java.lang.reflect.Field%2Cboolean%29).

When it is determined you can't access `final static` fields (because, the `setAccessible` override doesn't works but non-static final fields, but not for `static` final fields), it will keep failing for every subsequent reflection, even through a different `Field` object, because it keeps using the same `FieldAccessor`.

(*) barring synchronization issues; as the source code for `Field` mentions in a comment:

> // NOTE that there is no synchronization used here. It is correct
>   (though not efficient) to generate more than one FieldAccessor for a
>   given Field.

Comment: as a side note, as I was testing the above code, I used the "working" version and then immediately printed FOO to see the result. The bytecode was probably optimised to output a constant 5 because it knew the value was final and "cant" be changed.

Comment: @slipperyseal True, constants in `static final` fields are inlined. It is easier to observe effects if you make it a non-constant, for example like this: `private static final int FOO = new Integer(5);`

Comment: I was hoping there would be a better way, but that makes sense.

Comment: You may use `static final int FOO = Math.abs(5);` to prevent compile-time optimization without creating an `Integer` object. Or `static final int FOO; static { FOO = 5; }`. But keep in mind that this does not prevent runtime optimizations. In principle, the JVM is allowed to aggressively optimize `static final` fields without caring for reflective manipulations that are not allowed by the JLS. I strongly discourage from doing that; there is no imaginable scenario without a cleaner and even simpler alternative.